# Java - InvocationTargetException when casting List to ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist, invocationtargetexception

Say a class is defined like:

```
public class foodFactory{

    protected EList<food> Basket;

    public List<food> getBasket(){
        return Basket;
    }
}
```

The following throws exeption when I try to run it:

```
foodFactory factory = new foodFactory();

ArrayList<food> foodbasket;

foodbasket = (ArrayList<food>)getBasket();
```

And I'm not seeing why. Did I not cast it properly?

Comment: By the way, I'm not seeing the exception in your question.

Comment: Provide the full stack trace of your exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as long as `EList` is ot derived from `ArrayList`, there must be a ClassCastException.

```
List<food> foodbasket = (List<food>) factory.getBasket();
```

Don't use `ArrayList`, use the interface `List`.

[By the way, you should use the java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html).

Classnames start uppercase. Valiables are lowercase.

Comment: `org.eclipse.emf.common.util.EList` is what it probably is... no idea why you'd use it.

Comment: If it is a http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.8.0/org/eclipse/emf/common/util/EList.html than it cannot be castet to ArrayList, because ArrayList is not a parent class of EList.

Answer (score 0):

Is the factory a nested class? If not, shouldn't you be calling it like this?

```
foodFactory factory = new foodFactory();

List<food> foodbasket = (ArrayList<food>) factory.getBasket();
```

On another note, you should be using `foodbasket` as an `EList`.